# AWS - get the current project path while executing code on AWS Lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a requirement where I need to read the ini file from the current java project but I am unable to retrieve the path dynamically. I tried `System.getProperty("user.dir")` to fetch the path but it does not work. It works fine on local system but does not work on `AWS`. This code is running on `AWS Lambda` to handle the events on S3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just open it by referencing it in `./src/main/resources/myfile.ini`, assuming you have a maven style project.

Alternatively you can access it via the classpath

[How to really read text file from classpath in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java)

Comment: Yeah i figured that out. I added the files under the resource folder and accessing it using getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(xyz.properties). And you can do it by adding the file/folder path as a resource in pom.xml if you explicitly want to include a file/folder in your class path. Thanks for your input. –

Answer (score 1):

Try reading the value of the LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT environment variable:

```
final String projectPath = System.getenv("LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT");
```